# Remove graphic from background of PowerPoint slides

Tags: ms-office

I have an old slide deck and can not discover where a graphic "lives" in it. In the screenshot here we can see the `Slide Master` being edited - and specifically the *Footer* area.  The `scala` logo graphic is presently selected. That is a graphic I *do want*.

But the `10 Silicon Valley Code Camp` should be removed.

[image]

I can not select that second graphic (in order to delete it): in what layer or layout element should I look?

**Update** I had actually also checked the `Format Background from the`Slide Master`: here that is shown having only a *gradient* and not an image:

[image]

**Another update** Apparently the "bonus" graphic only shows up on the *first five slides*. So then I will look to see what is "special" about those first slides vs the rest..

**Me again..** Selecting *Hide Background Graphics* does do exactly that - but it is an "equal opportunity" option- it *also* hides the (desired) `scala` graphic.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's possible the image is part of the slide background.

1. From the Slide Master, choose Background Styles → Format Background….

   [image]
2. See if a picture has been inserted and replace it or change to another fill type.

   [image]

Comment: Thx.  I did check that before - I should have included the info in my question .. will update it.